# Regex - How can I swap two expressions in different lines?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm pretty new in Regex, but I want to swap two expressions in two different lines.
Here's the code:

```
translate italian ch1_a20cefa7:|

# "..."
msgstr "..."
```

I'd like to swap in:

```
translate italian ch1_a20cefa7:msgstr

# "..."
| "..."
```

As you can see, the `|` has been swapped with the `msgstr` part down there. How can I do it?
Also, there are multiple lines where I should apply this, and sometimes in front of the `|` you can find other letters or characters.
I was thinking about this:
`([|].*)` for the first part, but then I don't know how to find the `msgstr` (that it never changes).

Edit:

Here's other example of the code I'm talking about.

```
translate italian ch1_669664cb:| mc

# "Hey."
msgstr "Hey."


translate italian ch1_177d3eb2:| mc

# "What are you doing?"
msgstr "What are you doing?"


translate italian ch1_25d98ea6:| m p_1a

# "I'm in charge of the breakfast, remember?"
msgstr "I'm in charge of the breakfast, remember?"


translate italian ch1_7ae83e04:|

# "Oh, that's right."
msgstr "Oh, that's right."
```

I want it swapped like this:

```
translate italian ch1_669664cb:msgstr 

# "Hey."
| mc "Hey."


translate italian ch1_177d3eb2:msgstr 

# "What are you doing?"
| mc"What are you doing?"


translate italian ch1_25d98ea6:msgstr 

# "I'm in charge of the breakfast, remember?"
| m p_1a"I'm in charge of the breakfast, remember?"


translate italian ch1_7ae83e04:msgstr 

# "Oh, that's right."
|"Oh, that's right."
```

As you can see, sometimes there's something in front of the `|` but sometimes there's not.

Comment: You shouldn't dramatically change your question after other users have already answered it.

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, but I didn't "dramatically" change my question, I simply clarified what I was asking for since the start.
From my Original Question: "[...]and sometimes in front of the `|` you can find other letters or characters.".
Your answer was good, but not completed, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use 4 capturing groups and switch group 4 and 2 in the replacement

```
^(.*)(\|.*)(\n(?:(?!msgstr).*\n)*)(msgstr)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*)` Capture **group 1**, match any char 0+ times
- `(\|.*)` Capture **group 2** from the last occurrence of `|` until the end of the string in group 2
- `(\n(?:(?!msgstr).*\n)*)` Capture **group 3**, match all lines that don't start with `msgstr`
- `(msgstr)` Capture **group 4**, match `msgstr`

Replace with

```
$1$4$3$2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RrR9JN/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \|(.*?)msgstr
Replace: msgstr$1|
```

### Demo

The regex pattern matches a single pipe `|`, then it captures all content, across lines, until hitting the first instance of `msgstr`.  The replacement does the swap, with the pipe and `msgstr` swapping positions, with the captured content in between them unchanged.

**Edit:**

My answer assumes you are doing your regex replacement in dot all mode, where `.*` matches across lines.  If not, then use the following pattern instead:

```
Find:    \|([\s\S]*?)msgstr
Replace: msgstr$1|
```

Note: This answer was given to the original question, which the OP has dramatically changed since I posted this answer.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you answer. I tried to copy your expression but it doesn't work.
I'm using Atom, if it helps!

Comment: You should tell us what regex tool/language you are using.  My answer certainly does work in the demo, and would also work in tools like Notepad++ and probably most IDEs.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I'm using Atom for the RegEx, in your demo works as I want, but in my tool it doesn't. As I said, I'm new in this, should I do something on Atom?

Comment: Yes...did you enable DOT ALL mode in your regex replacement?  Check my updated answer for an alternative which might work in Atom without you having to change anything.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, your edit is perfect, the only thing is that I'd like to swap the rest of the line after the `|`.
As I said, since sometimes in other lines there could be some other letters or characters I'd like to swap them too.

Example:

`translate italian ch1_a20cefa7:| mc `

Again, sorry for bothering you!

Comment: Honestly I can't really edit my question just based on your comment, because it isn't very clear.  You should either edit your question and reveal the real problem, or maybe ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

replace `/^(translate .*):\|$/` => `$1:msgstr` 
then replace all `/^msgstr\b/` => `|`

I'm not sure we are understanding your question. 
Can you extend your example?

EDIT: I'm late, can you test:

```
Search: /^(translate\b[^:]*:)([^\n]*)\n(.*)msgstr/gmsU
Replace: $1mgstr\n$3$2
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jZekRH/1

Comment: I extended my question, you should now understand it better! Sorry if I didn't clarified myself.